# Why is flex-fill not creating equal width in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

According to [Bootstrap 4.1 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#fill) regarding the `.flex-fill` class

> Use the .flex-fill class on a series of sibling elements to force them into equal widths while taking up all available horizontal space.

I've made an example using `.flex-fill` on 3 siblings, but they are not forced into equal width.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="flex-fill">Item</div>
  <div class="flex-fill">Another</div>
  <div class="flex-fill">Last item</div>
</div>
```

How can that be?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Bootstrap’s `flex-fill` is unfortunately a very bad class. It sets the following `flex` CSS properties:

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
```

The grow and shrink values are fine. This is what makes the boxes share the available space evenly. The [`auto` flex-basis value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#Properties_applied_to_flex_items) however is not good:

> The `flex-basis` is what defines the size of that item in terms of the space it leaves as available space. The initial value of this property is `auto` — in this case the browser looks to see if the items have a size. […]
>
> If the items don’t have a size then the content's size is used as the flex-basis. This is why when we just declare `display: flex` on the parent to create flex items, the items all move into a row and take only as much space as they need to display their contents.

So `flex-basis: auto` makes the boxes have the width that the content needs. And only **then**, the growing and shrinking is applied to fill the remaining size of the container.

If you take a look at the output from your example, this is what you can see:

[image: Measured widths of the whitespace]

The columns are obviously not of the same width, but those blue boxes, which is the whitespace in each flex item, they all have the same width. So what is evened out is the remaining space, without taking the content into account.

Of course, this is rarely what you want to do. The most common thing to do with a flex box is to make all items have the same width. Without bootstrap, you would just do `flex: 1` for this, which is the shorthand for `flex: 1 1 0;`

```css
.flex-even {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="flex-even">Item</div>
  <div class="flex-even">Another</div>
  <div class="flex-even">Last item</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, that is not what the Bootstrap authors made their `flex-fill` to be. And to make matters worse, [the example they are showing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#fill) is using the same content in every flex item, so you don’t actually *see* that behavior. There’s also [an issue about this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26803), which may eventually clear up this misunderstanding in the docs.

Bottom line though: Bootstrap has no built-in `flex: 1` class (at least to my knowledge), so you’re best off creating one for your own. It’s definitely the more useful “flex-fill”.

Comment: There is a small trick for avoiding the definition of the custom class `flex-even`. It is to use the standard bs4 class `media-body`. It exactly sets `flex: 1`.

Comment: ^^ Really helpful tip. But if you need this class to be responsive, you'll have to create another utility class...

Comment: You can merge on into bootstraps utilities file via SASS as such

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "flex-even": (
      responsive: true,
      property: flex,
      values: (even: 1)
    )
  )  
);

Boom now you have flex-even and flex-xs-even etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same question, wanting to leverage Flexbox and not just "classic" Bootstrap code (my mind is sometimes on version 3, not 4).

It seems that Bootstrap 4's .col-* classes use flexbox under the hood to do just that! They're using the shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` to achieve the 50% width. It *does* come with having to use `.row` as a wrapper around each `.col-*` class, however.

(*This code is from the browser dev tools*)

```css
.col-md-6 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```